# Sending command to a device over Bluetooth by writing to DataOutputStream

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, serial-port, dataoutputstream

I'm trying to send a command to a device over my Bluetooth RFCOMM socket Connection.
-Connection is successful.
-As soon as it gets connected i tried reading the DataInputStream and i continuously get data from the device.
-My problem is i'm trying to send a Serial command to the device and on doing that my device doesn't respond to the command.

Is there something wrong in the way i'm sending commands ?  Here is the code i used ...

```
 DataOutputStream Dos = new DataOutputStream(BTsocket.getOutputStream());
 ...........

String message = "SET TIME XXX";
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
    try {

        Dos.writeInt(msgBuffer.length);
        Dos.write(msgBuffer); 
        Dos.flush();

   } 
   catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write.", e);
    }
```

Comment: In the DataInputStream the device continuosly sends data. So if i send a command over DataOutputStream how can i know the return status of the command.

Comment: could you please provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that i have to have proper Escape Sequence while sending the command. It worked after correcting the Escape Sequence.